# How can I detect "Sheet - Create" using Smartsheet API

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

**Background**

- We will be creating / managing projects in Smartsheet
- Each new project is a new sheet, based on a template
- I am designing integration to other systems that need to be notified
  whenever a new project or task within a project is created.
- I can use a Webhook to detect changes within a project (sheet)
- It doesn’t look like I can use a Webhook to detect that a new sheet has been created because, according to the documentation, the only scope available for webhooks is “sheet” – I think I would need a webhook scoped to “workspace” to detect new sheets when the are created within the workspace

**My question**

How can I detect when a new sheet (project) has been created programmatically in order to trigger the necessary actions that need to occur in other systems?

**Related question**

I see that there is an Event Reporting add-on that does publish an event on SHEET – CREATE. Can you provide more information about this add-on?

Answer (score 2):

The [API docs](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-events) show some examples of how to use event reporting.

For example:

```
// Example 1: Return events starting from the oldest event available
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/events?since=2010-01-01T00:00:00Z \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ll352u9jujauoqz4gstvsae05" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
```

Look for events with a `objectType` of `SHEET`, and an `action` of `CREATE`.

The [event reporting docs](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/event-reporting-docs/) can give you a full listing of the available options.